# can a html5 form be submitted and then returned on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Not sure if this is the correct wording but if I have a html5 form which is located in a specified sidebar of a page, on submission can I basically just reload the sidebar? or does a duplicate page have to be loaded with the sidebar just changed?

I'm not even sure how to approach this;

firstly, whether it can be done in this manner and

secondly, what javascript would be involved.

The form submission is only client-side as I do not need to worry about security and 'actually' sending the filled out form information just yet.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=submit+form+via+ajax

Comment: You can do that. You'll need to use a combination of `jquery.ajax()` and `jquery.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery library & AJAX to achieve something like this, I made a little demonstration (w/o any AJAX though)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<form id="sidebarform" onsubmit="return false;">
    Textbox:<input type="text" id="sidebarformtext"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="sidebarformsubmit">
</form> 
</div>
<script>
$("#sidebarformsubmit").click( function(){
    $("#sidebarform").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#sidebar").html($("#sidebarformtext").val() )
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will fadeout the form, and replace it with the text put into the textfield, I hope this helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after. Sorry for being a bit 'dumb' when it comes to this but what exactly does the AJAX do? 
Also in order to enforce any constraints on the form would have to follow these procedures in addition to what you have written above, or is there someway I can combine them? Again, sorry for being daft on the topic.

Comment: Like for instance, currently if I have a 'required' attribute on the input and I press submit, it will fade and then display "this field is required".

Comment: AJAX is used by Google for example, showing you suggestions while you're typing, you can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: @homer5677 Regarding your other question, then I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, how can I prevent the form fields fading if nothing is entered into the box. I meant to link this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Would I follow what is here and then implement your code?
No wonder it didn't make sense-forgot the link!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do might be to load the sidebar on a iframe. This way the page will load separately from rest of page.. and form submits will work independently of rest of page